# Visual Studio on MacBook

Tags: macos, apache, cordova, visual-studio-2012, mobile

I'm new to programming, and still learning. Anyway, is it possible to use Visual Studio for Apache Cordova on OS X? Or do I have to use Virtual Machine for Windows?

If I want to make apps for both iOS and Android, do I need to write my code twice? (Hybrid Mobile App).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio on your mac by running Windows 8.1 or 10 in a virtual machine or using bootcamp to boot directly into windows 8.1 or 10.

I personally use the virtual machine approach for my development.  Using a Mac with a Windows VM I can target iOS, Android, and Windows Phone. You can read my blog post here on how to setup your environment (you might also want to check out part 1 as well):

http://trunica.net/building-hybrid-mobile-apps-part-2.html

No you do not need to write your code twice. That's the beauty of Cordova! About 95% to close 100% of your code should be exactly the same across the platforms.

You can use Cordova directly on your Mac if you want and develop for both iOS and Android without using Visual Studio.  I do however recommend using Visual Studio since it adds a lot of nice features for development (additional emulators, easier configuration, etc...).

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I'm very grateful for your answer and opinions. Now I can stop thinking about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as Brad said, you can't use Visual Studio without a Windows. But, the Visual Studio Development Team built a CLI called TACO (Tools for Apache Cordova)
With that cli, you have some features very cool for beginners. Take a look http://taco.tools/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you! TACO looks very exciting. Definitely gonna try it out!